# What is the simplest jQuery Dropdown plugin?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, drop-down-menu

In your experience, what is the simplest jQuery flyout menu plugin that does not try to do too much, and is simple to modify?

i am working on a more interactive "like" system. When a user mouseover the link, he should be able to "like" it as usual, but also be able to do more interactions easily

Comment: Any details about what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: Do you mean dropdown menus or a customisable wrapper for a `select` element?

Comment: @alex dropdown menu. select element is too... heavy probably

Comment: @ming yeow I *undeleted* my answer.

Comment: @ming yeow: I have edited your question to be more comprehensive. I have changed "dropdown" with "flyout menu"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [jQuery SuckerFish](http://be.twixt.us/jquery/suckerFish.php)

[image: jQuery SuckerFish]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [select menu](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/http:/doggdot.us/), a wonderful plugin that will be part of the jQuery UI project in the near future

Please note that the latest plugin version is now maintained by someone at https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/

Comment: thank you! This certainly looks powerful. It is a little too much for this particular need, but i will be using it in the future for sure

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a easy dropdown menu, I would recommend the suckerfish.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples

Comment: got it, this is exactly what i would use!